# SonarQube BuildBreaker plugin blocks local analysis

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

When enable build breaker plugin in sonarqube, I found there is no way to run local analysis anymore, because the analysis finishes with failures. And no detail issue list is available. It blcoks usage of the plugin, as developer cannot examine locally whether their check-in may break the build before submitting their changes, but if the change is submitted the build will break...
Currently what I can imagine is installing another server for local analysis by disabling build breaker plugin, but it brings other issues like synchronizing configurations between two different sonar instances. Any better idea?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way is adding a local analysis property in the sonar plugin configuration:

`sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true`

[image]

This way the sonar analysis during build willl break by the build breaker plugin, in the meantime developer can analyze and fix issues locally in Eclipse before check-in.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "local" analysis?

Most methods of running Sonar (runner, ANT plugin, Maven plugin) will always contact the Sonar server and attempt to upload analysis results. My advise is to run Sonar as a post-build step in your integration server (I can highly recommend Jenkins). This ensures only a single machine talks to Sonar and has the secondary benefit of keeping the Sonar credentials secure.

The only true way to perform local analysis is to run Sonar within Eclipse (using the Sonar Eclipse plugin). This is the recommended way to achieve your desired use-case where developers analyze before committing code (which could then be picked up by your integration server, automatically updating Sonar).

Note:

- In eariler versions of Sonar an error would be thrown if more than one analysis run was performed at the same time. More recent versions have a locking mechanism to prevent parallel updates of sonar server, which might explain your observation of builds being "blocked".
- Sonar is a thick client application. Analysis happens as part of the build process and results are afterwards uploaded to the server.